# How to create list of studuent in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create list of Students,
I'm having a problem with how to make an automatic list.

List of students :

```
Name: student1 | RegistrationNumber:1
Name: student2 | RegistrationNumber:2
Name: student3 | RegistrationNumber:3
```

Comment: There are probably a number of ways to make a "list" in C#. You can do an internet search and find lots of examples. What do you plan to do with the list after you make it? That could indicate what specific method you use would be most appropriate.

Comment: The easiest would be `var student List = new List<Student> {new Student ("student1", 1), new Student ("student2", 2), ...}`, assuming you have a `Student` class with the appropriate properties and a constructor that populates them

Comment: Increase Register bumber in Constructor of student class

Answer (score 1):

> This is the easiest way you can create a List in C#.

```
List<Object> Students = new List<Object>()
        {
            new { Name = "student1",RegistrationNumber = 1 },
            new { Name = "student2",RegistrationNumber = 2 },
            new { Name = "student2",RegistrationNumber = 3 }
        };
```

> Here I have created a list of Object but a better way is to create a
> Class that encapsulates required data.

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student () { Name = "student1",RegistrationNumber = 1 },
            new Student () { Name = "student2",RegistrationNumber = 2 },
            new Student () { Name = "student2",RegistrationNumber = 3 }
        };


        public class Student
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int RegistrationNumber { get; set; }
        }
```